# Set Time Range of a Zend Dojo TextTimeBox

Tags: zend-framework, dojo

Hi is it possible to set the time range of a Dojo textTimeBox to 09:00 - 18:30.

I can't find anything in either the Zend or Dojo documentation that show how this can be done or if it can be done.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set max and min constraints for widget:

```
new dijit.form.TimeTextBox({
    name: "prog_val",
    value: new Date(),
    constraints: {
        timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss',
        clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
        visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
        visibleRange: 'T01:00:00',
        min:'T09:00:00',
        max:'T18:30:00'
    }
    },
    "prog_val");
```

It does not allow the user to enter data beyond the allowed values.
However this still allows user to scroll to the disabled times, user just cannot select them.

For hiding disabled times you should do some hack :)

You should override `_getFilteredNodes` method of `dijit._TimePicker`. For example :

```
dojo.declare("my._TimePicker", dijit._TimePicker, {
                // extend the default show() method
                _getFilteredNodes: function (/*number*/start, /*number*/maxNum, /*Boolean*/before) {
                    // summary:
                    //      Returns an array of nodes with the filter applied.  At most maxNum nodes
                    //      will be returned - but fewer may be returned as well.  If the
                    //      before parameter is set to true, then it will return the elements
                    //      before the given index
                    // tags:
                    //      private
                    var nodes = [], n, i = start, max = this._maxIncrement + Math.abs(i),
                chk = before ? -1 : 1, dec = before ? 1 : 0, inc = before ? 0 : 1;
                    do {
                        i = i - dec;
                        var date = new Date(this._refDate);
                        var incrementDate = this._clickableIncrementDate;
                        date.setHours(date.getHours() + incrementDate.getHours() * i,
                    date.getMinutes() + incrementDate.getMinutes() * i,
                    date.getSeconds() + incrementDate.getSeconds() * i);
                        if (!this.isDisabledDate(date)) {
                            n = this._createOption(i);
                            if (n) { nodes.push(n); }
                        }
                        i = i + inc;
                    } while (nodes.length < maxNum && (i * chk) < max);
                    if (before) { nodes.reverse(); }
                    return nodes;
                }

            });
```

And you need to set this new class ('my._TimePicker') as a popupClass property of your text time box:

dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
    dijit.byId("prog_val").popupClass = "my._TimePicker";
});

And you can see : [it works](http://pastehtml.com/view/aud06r0ai.html)!

Comment: Thanks for that I'll have to look at the hack option as this is what I need. I'm new to Zend and Dojo so may take some time :-) I was wondering about the max and min but I was trying to set them using 'min' => 'T09:00:00